# How to translate "Legs curl" in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, sport

I'm a work-out/gym/musculation athlete and I must speak about this exercize, but I have to use only French words.
How could I translate "legs curl" in French?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il s'agit généralement de ***flexion(s) des jambes*** (nom féminin, *une flexion, des flexions* ; [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18052619), [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=LEG%20CURL&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) ; on trouve aussi des termes plus techniques qui réfèrent au groupe de muscles impliqués (*flexion des ischio-jambiers*) ou qui précisent l'appareil employé (*flexion de jambes au banc à ischios* ; i.e. banc = *bench*). Probablement que le terme en anglais est [reconnu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leg_curl) en français (par exemple : exercice de *leg curl* debout i.e. *standing*) ; si on n'est pas certain que l'auditoire comprenne on peut l'employer concurremment (i.e. *one may use the English language term alongside the French language one to make sure people understand*).